# connect directly to an IP address

Tags: curl, server, proxy, cdn, cloudflare

I have two servers for my website. both of them are behind a proxy like cloudflare for ddos protection and cdn. with having actual IP addresses of my servers, how can I make a direct request to them for troubleshooting (for example with curl)?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1587335/replace-server-address-by-ip-in-curl

Comment: tl;dr if you just want to bypass your CDN altogether, use the IP address instead of the DNS name for your server e.g. `curl <ip address>`. If that doesn't work, consult the link above.